# Eclipse Task tag cannot be marked as completed, why?

Tags: eclipse

I have created a task tag TODO by typing `//TODO (some text)`, now I want to mark it as completed but when I right click on it in the *Tasks* view, the *Mark Completed* option is grayed out or unavailable. How can I mark it as completed?

Please help me. thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse Task List - Mark Completed is not Active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288691/eclipse-task-list-mark-completed-is-not-active)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a bug in [eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=309567). You cannot Mark it Completed if you just write it `// TODO`, you can only mark it completed if you create a task using right click then [Add Task](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_task_management.htm).

If you don't want to remove `// TODO` you can create another task flag **Preferences->Java->Compiler->Task** for example COMPLETE, then put it after your TODO.

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288691/eclipse-task-list-mark-completed-is-not-active)

Comment: if this helps you can accept the answer on clicking the check to resolve this quesion

Comment: is this really a bug or just different functionality: `Task` (Mylyn stuff)  and `Task Tag` (Editor stuff)...